# Auto-Suggest Source from JS-Chrome-Content Function in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

Regarding Mozillas [Auto-Suggest Extension Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_implement_custom_autocomplete_search_component) I'd like to design my own auto-suggest extension. The tutorial uses json defined in the `autocompletesearchparam` param as suggestion-source.

How would I define another source, like a library method from a chrome-content js-file that returns an object?

Answer (score 2):

Just grab that object and serialize it, using something like `JSON.stringify()` (assuming its in the format that the extension wants, if not, you'll need to manipulate your object). Now attach your result string to the the "autocompletesearchparam" attribute or "searchParam" property of your  element. Should be as simple as that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify